# zoom in and zoom out button

Tags: android, button

I wrote this code for a zoom in and zoom out button;
they worked but with wrong algorithm. both of them increase the size!? and although I say increase smoothly(only 0.01f per click) but with clicking on them size increase about 50%(it became too large) and that is my problem.

```
final TextView rbc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rbc);
rbc.setText(R.string.start);
sizeup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            float textsize = rbc.getTextSize();
            textsize += 0.05f;
            rbc.setTextSize(textsize);

        }
    });
    sizedown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            float textsize = rbc.getTextSize();
            textsize -= 0.05f;
            rbc.setTextSize(textsize);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixed units problem. The default method setTextSize(float) assumes you're inputting sp units (scaled pixels), while the getTextSize() method returns an exact pixel size.

You should use this:

```
this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

This will make sure you're working with the same units.

Comment: I do not get it!could you explain more?

Comment: Instead of `rbc.setTextSize(textsize);` use `rbc.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);` in both Listeners. The latest uses textsize as px (pixel units) as you got from `rbc.getTextSize()`